# Pandas - Find String and return adjacent values for the matched data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to write a piece of code to achieve/overcome below problem.

I have two excel spreadsheets. Lets take as an example

```
DF1 -  1. Master Data 
DF2 - 2. consumer details.
```

I need to iterate description column in Consumer details which contains string or sub string which is in Master data sheet and return a adjacent value. I understand, its pretty straight forward and simple but unable to succeed.

I was using Index Match in Excel -

```
INDEX('Path\[Master Sheet.xlsx]Master 
List'!$B$2:$B$199,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH('path\[Master 
Sheet.xlsx]Master List'!$A$2:$A$199,B3)),0))
```

But need a solution in Python/Pandas -

```
Eg Df1 - Master SheetMaster Sheet -
Store       Category
Nike        Shoes
GAP         Clothing
Addidas     Shoes
Apple       Electronics
Abercrombie Clothing
Hollister       Clothing
Samsung     Electornics
Netflix     Movies  

etc.....

df2 - Consumer Sheet-

Date     Description    Amount   Category
01/01/20  GAP Stores    1.1     
01/01/20  Apple Limited 1000
01/01/20  Aber fajdfal  50
01/01/20  hollister das 20
01/01/20  NETFLIX.COM   10  
01/01/20  GAP Kids      5.6
```

Now, I need to update Category column in consumer sheet based on description(string/substring) column in consumer sheet referring to stores column in master sheet

Any inputs/suggestion, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a custom function that loops through the `Df1` values in order to match a store to a string provided as an argument. if a match if found it will `return` the associated category string and if none is found `return` `None` or some other default value. You can use `str.lower` to increase the chances of a match being found. You then use `pandas.Series.apply` to apply this function to the column you want to try and find matches in.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Store = ['Nike','GAP','Addidas','Apple','Abercrombie'],
    Category = ['Shoes','Clothing','Shoes','Electronics','Clothing'],
))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Date = ['01/01/20','01/01/20','01/01/20'],
    Description = ['GAP Stores','Apple Limited','Aber fajdfal'],
    Amount = [1.1,1000,50],
))

def get_cat(x):
    global df1
    for store, cat in df1[['Store','Category']].values:
        if store.lower() in x.lower():
            return cat

df2['Category'] = df2['Description'].apply(get_cat)

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
       Date    Description  Amount     Category
0  01/01/20     GAP Stores     1.1     Clothing
1  01/01/20  Apple Limited  1000.0  Electronics
2  01/01/20   Aber fajdfal    50.0         None
```

[Python tutor link to example](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf1%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Store%20%3D%20%5B'Nike','GAP','Addidas','Apple','Abercrombie'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Category%20%3D%20%5B'Shoes','Clothing','Shoes','Electronics','Clothing'%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adf2%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Date%20%3D%20%5B'01/01/20','01/01/20','01/01/20'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Description%20%3D%20%5B'GAP%20Stores','Apple%20Limited','Aber%20fajdfal'%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20Amount%20%3D%20%5B1.1,1000,50%5D,%0A%29%29%0A%0Adef%20get_cat%28x%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20global%20df1%0A%20%20%20%20for%20store,%20cat%20in%20df1%5B%5B'Store','Category'%5D%5D.values%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20store.lower%28%29%20in%20x.lower%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20cat%0A%0Adf2%5B'Category'%5D%20%3D%20df2%5B'Description'%5D.apply%28get_cat%29%0A%0Aprint%28df2%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=9&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

I should note that if `'Aber fajdfal'` is supposed to match to `'Abercrombie'` then this solution is not going to work. You'll need to add more complex logic to the function in order to match partial strings like that.